# How to reset styles on pressing enter in contenteditable div

Tags: contenteditable

I'm attempting to remove all styles and any potential child tags when the Enter key is pressed inside a contenteditable element. The default behavior of wrapping new lines with a div is acceptable, but if the previous line had any styling, it gets copied to the new line as well. Is there a way to completely remove all styles and potential child tags when the Enter key is pressed?

Current behavior:

```
<div><span style="color: blue;">hi</span></div> // press enter after hi 
<div><span style="color: blue;"></span></div> // will create this
```

I would like to create an empty div like it already does but without any styling:

```
<div><span style="color: blue;">hi</span></div> // press enter after hi 
<div></div> // always create empty div
```

I have tried using 'insertParagraph' and 'insertHTML with document.execCommand(, false, 'div');
with no success.